# How to check if some string is illegal for Realm?

Tags: string, unicode, realm

In my project user may enter some Unicode text like: §○✫፠ஃΩ❆火✈❀雨✕❤✌中.

But how can I be sure that sending this string to Realm database wouldn't lead to some exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation defines only next limitations:

- [Size limitations](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#general):

  > `Strings` and byte arrays (`byte[]`) cannot be larger than 16 MB
- [Sorting and querying limitations](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sorting-and-querying-on-string):

  > Sorting and case insensitive string matches in queries are only supported for character sets in ‘Latin Basic’, ‘Latin Supplement’, ‘Latin Extended A’, ‘Latin Extended B’ (UTF-8 range 0-591). In addition, setting the case insensitive flag in queries when using `equalTo()`, `notEqualTo()`, `contains()`, `endsWith()`, `beginsWith()` or `like()` will only work on characters from the English locale.

Other usage of `String`'s fields is fully supported